# How can correct the draw function in Tic-Tac-Toe game?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

```
    for i in range(1, 10):

        valid_move = False
        while not valid_move:
            move = (input("Player1 your turn with X. Please choose a cell: "))
            if not move.isdigit():
                print("Please insert a cell number from 1-9.")

            else:
                valid_move = make_move(player1,move)
                if valid_move:
                    printBoard(theBoard)
                    break

        if (theBoard['7'] == theBoard['8'] == theBoard['9'] == player1) or \
                (theBoard['4'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['6'] == player1) or \
                (theBoard['1'] == theBoard['2'] == theBoard['3'] == player1) or \
                (theBoard['7'] == theBoard['4'] == theBoard['1'] == player1) or \
                (theBoard['8'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['2'] == player1) or \
                (theBoard['9'] == theBoard['6'] == theBoard['3'] == player1) or \
                (theBoard['7'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['3'] == player1) or \
                (theBoard['9'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['1'] == player1):
            print("Player1 wins!")
            theBoard = {key: ' ' for key in theBoard}  # Reset the board
            break


        valid_move = False
        while not valid_move:
            move = (input("Player2 your turn with O. Please choose a cell: "))
            if not move.isdigit():
                print("Please insert a cell number.")

            else:
                valid_move = make_move(player2, move)
                if valid_move:
                    printBoard(theBoard)
                    break

        if (theBoard['7'] == theBoard['8'] == theBoard['9'] == player2) or \
                (theBoard['4'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['6'] == player2) or \
                (theBoard['1'] == theBoard['2'] == theBoard['3'] == player2) or \
                (theBoard['7'] == theBoard['4'] == theBoard['1'] == player2) or \
                (theBoard['8'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['2'] == player2) or \
                (theBoard['9'] == theBoard['6'] == theBoard['3'] == player2) or \
                (theBoard['7'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['3'] == player2) or \
                (theBoard['9'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['1'] == player2):
            print("Player2 wins!")
            theBoard = {key: ' ' for key in theBoard}  # Reset the board
            break


        `if i == 9:
            print("It's a draw!")
            theBoard = {key: ' ' for key in theBoard}
            break  # Reset the board`

elif start_question.lower() == "no":
    print("The game is over.")
    game = False

else:
    print("Please respond 'Yes' or 'No'.")
```

I was trying to use the function in order to stop the tic-tac-toe game after the 9th round, which implifies the draw of the game. However, the function is not triggered and doesn't react if all 9 rounds have gone.

I tried to implement the function, which would stop a game when the 9 rounds are gone.

Comment: Why do you have backticks around the `if i == 9: ...` code?

Comment: Why us there a tilde next to your if statement? Code would not run with this, not sure if intentional.

Comment: You do two rounds of the game in each iteration of the loop, one for player 1, another for player 2. So you'll fill up the board after 4.5 iterations, not 9.

Comment: A draw happens after player 1 plays in round 5 if they haven't won.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `i == 9` is not true at the moment of a draw. The draw occurs earlier, since in every iteration of your loop *two* moves are made. If a draw is reached, it will always be the first player that plays the last move (their fifth move), so the draw-check should be made before the second player takes their turn.

So the solution is to move this block:

```
if i == 9:
    print("It's a draw!")
    theBoard = {key: ' ' for key in theBoard}
    break
```

... and place it just before `valid_move = False` (half-way the loop's body), and change the condition:

```
if i == 5:
    print("It's a draw!")
    theBoard = {key: ' ' for key in theBoard}
    break
```

You can then also change the `for` loop's range, although it is not absolutely necessary as the loop will always end with a `break`.

Unlrelated, but there are many things that can be improved in your code. Some high-level hints:

- Don't mix game logic and printing in the same function: instead keep your functions dedicated to either printing (like `printBoard`: good example), or business logic (like `make_move`, which I hope, doesn't print). The main loop should then only call functions of either type.
- Don't repeat similar code (like checking for a win, getting input from the user, ...etc), but instead make more functions (one could be `is_win`) that take argument(s) to cover for the slight differences (like: which player), and introduce the concept of toggling the player, so that you can reuse the same code for a different player.

Comment: Thank you for your help, trincot!

It solved my problem. Thank you for some advice from your side. I am just a beginner and it is my first attempts. However, I will take the points from you into the consideration.